# SQL Server Numa config - Why is VAS reservered memory different on each numa mode?

Tags: sql-server, memory, numa

I have a virtual machine running on hyper-V. The VM has 26 processors assigned to it and 300 GB of RAM.
The underlying physical server has 2 CPU sockets, both with 8 cores each.

Looking at the NUMA config in SQL Server I can see the following:

> Node: 0 State: ONLINE Online schedulers: 13 Offline schedulers: 0
> Processor Group: 0 Memory node: 0 Memory VAS Reserved GB: 688
>
> Node: 1 State: ONLINE Online schedulers: 13 Offline schedulers: 0
> Processor Group: 0 Memory node: 1 Memory VAS Reserved GB: 0

Why is there a difference of Reserved VAS memory between the two numa modes?  Does it mean all the RAM is in the first processors DIMMs on the physical server, and so the second processor is actually having to access the RAM on the first?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you post top 150 lines of `sp_readerrorlog`. This may be normal thing but just trying to see if you have some specialized configuration

Comment: Virtual Address Space (VAS) reservation is not reserved memory.

Comment: See: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/283944/numa-config-sp-blitz-output

Comment: @brian VAS is actually reserved when SQL Server starts. If you are hinting towards that it is not reserved.

Comment: @Shanky More that address space is not equal to memory / RAM.

Comment: Yep I know that but the point of discussion was VAS is not reserved which you said but I am saying it is reserved at startup and before memory is allocated it must be first mapped to VAS region and then to physical memory for it to actually commit.